# Connecting to service provider on SIM7000A chip through Verizon tower

Tags: arduino, at-command

I have a SIM7000A device that sees the Verizon tower.  I am using Ting wireless SIM to create an IoT device to send emergency information to a homeowner.  The SIM works on T-Mobile and Verizon networks.
You can see the tower:
[image]

I have selected the wireless.dish.com APN to connect to.

[image]

When I try to connect I get this:

[image]

My IMEI number is a registered device with Ting.  I've verified that.

Using the AT Command Tester for Simcom Modules I get an error when I try to check the Preferred Operators list.  I'm not sure if this has anything to do with it.

[image]

It seems like when I try to connect, Verizon is trying to validate my device and halting me.  How do I connect "through" Verizon's network to the Ting network?

Comment: Is your sim card a NB-IoT simcard or just a LTE simcard?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know.  I think it is just a "regular" sim card for a phone.  I didn't know there were different types.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured it out.  The SIM7000A is not compatible with the Verizon network.  According to the person I spoke with at Ting.com, this device only works on T-mobile.  With that network, it is not even worth trying to distribute my product to consumers if it uses this chip.  I show AT&T as available from this chip but it won't connect to Ting.com regardless.  She said it is only compatible with T-Mobile.

I guess I will have to find a new chip.

Comment: Well, [SIM7000A](http://www.simcom.com/product/SIM7000X.html) does not support GSM networks, it only works as NB-IOT/CAT-M1 device. You might need to find a SIM7000G which supports quad-band GSM. Verizon does supports NB-IoT on 700 MHz Band 13 LTE, 1900 MHz Band 2 LTE, 1700/2100 MHz Band 4 LTE. Maybe Ting.com SIM doesn't support NB-IoT and works for GSM, and SIM7000A happened not supporting GSM.

Comment: According to the Verizon website, they do support the SIM7000A. You can check here: https://opendevelopment.verizonwireless.com/design-and-build/approved-modules